# Node express API not responding well to Angular $http calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, http

What's happening is that I can't get succesfully loged in into the Node API when hitting the login route from the website via Angular $http.post() request, But it does Works pretty well when testing from postman (rest api test application).

Here is the client side code (api calls):

```
 function($http, $scope) {
      $scope.$watch('search', function() {
        fetch();
      });
      $scope.username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
      $scope.password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';        
      function fetch() {
        $scope.details="";
        $http.post("http://apiadress.demo/auth/login?username=" + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password)
          .then(function(response) {
            $scope.details = response.data.state;
          console.log(response);
          });
      }   
    }
```

this call produces the response:

```
{
  "state": "fail",
  "user": null
}
```

When making the same call from postma client responses the espected:

```
{
      "state": "success",
      "user": {
        "_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "username": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "__v": 0,
        "created_at": "2016-12-21T21:57:32.663Z"
      }
    }
```

My server side routing code is:

```
//log in
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/auth/success',
    failureRedirect: '/auth/failure'
}));

//responses whit successful login state
router.get('/success', function(req, res){
    res.send({state: req.user ? 'success' : 'fail', user: req.user ?req.user : null});
});
```

As you can see the user seems to be authenticeted but no data is being passed on the redirection when the api is called from angular... O.o

Answer (score 2):

From the website you are sending user data (username/password) through URL (which is technically for GET requests) but you should send it as POST data since it's a POST request. Here is how you would do this:

```
$http.post("http://apiadress.demo/auth/login", {
    username: $scope.username,
    password: $scope.password
}).then( success, failure );
```